# How to set decimal format in Kendo UI MVC NumericTextbox

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to display decimal(10,2) value on kendo numerictextbox. I tried following code but is not working:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox()  
    .Name("XYZ")  
    .Decimals(2)  
    .Step(0)  
    .Spinners(false)  
    .Format("########.##")  
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @maxlength = "11" }))
```

Also I tried `Format("n2")`, `Format("c2")` but nothing is working.

Comment: @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox()
.Name("XYZ").Format("n2") should work here. Can you provide more details? Could it be custom JavaScript that's overriding the format?

Comment: Format("n2") is correct for numbers and Format("c2") for currency.

Comment: .Format("#.00") do the trick.